# Django 1.8 CSS load incompletely

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have looked up almost every solution about Django CSS, JS, images file not load. However, I think my project is something different.

I want to make a RWD site but it doesn't work on the small screen.
No menu, No change the template.

I can see the CSS works but is not entirely.
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbnHV.jpg)

Trying everything I can find solutions. I confuse with the static file and path what is the correct level.

[Here is my project path Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8Tup.jpg)

I try so many methods and I delete those not really involved to keep the code clean for someone can help me.

settings.py

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templated-EX').replace('\\', '/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'coreapp/static')

STATIC_DIRS = [
    ('css',os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'css').replace('\\','/') ),  
    ('js',os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'js').replace('\\','/') ), 
    ('images',os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'images').replace('\\','/') ), 
    # ('upload',os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'upload').replace('\\','/') ), 
    ]
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Ex Machina by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ex Machina by TEMPLATED</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="{% static "js/html5shiv.js" %}"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/init.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-desktop.css"/>
```

Also I have tried to add something to urls.py. It couldn't be improved either.

I'm new to Django and must lost something important. I have stuck a few days.

---

update 0810

OK, guys,

I think I'm getting more clear than before. I try to download another template and build a new project. Doing the procedure again.

New project is fine! So the procedure is right.

I exam the original template I mentioned that is a little different with mine.
The different is html and CSS.

Original CSS in index.html

```
<noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/skel-noscript.css" %}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style-desktop.css" %}"/>
</noscript>
```

It doesn't work if you are using `<noscript></noscript>` in the html. Perhaps I deleted `<noscript></noscript>` because Django couldn't run with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your href in html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/skel-noscript.css" />
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Edit:
What is your BASE_DIR settings?
Can you try with following settings.

```
# Static Files
STATIC_ROOT = join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static'), ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: Can you try and answer question above ? Try above edited setting?

Comment: I try the bellow and get `STATIC_ROOT = join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
NameError: name 'join' is not defined`

Comment: BASE_DIR settings  



`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: add in your settings:
from os.path import join

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
{% load staticfiles %}
<!--
    Ex Machina by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ex Machina by TEMPLATED</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="{% static "js/html5shiv.js" %}"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{% static 'js/skel.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/skel-panels.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/init.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="{% static 'css/skel-noscript.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'css/style-desktop.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

You weren't properly using `{% load staticfiles %}`